# Ubuntu18.04LTS デスクトップ版で無線LANが使えない

Tags: ubuntu, network

以前はWindowsOSを入れていたパソコンに新しくUbuntuを入れました。WindowsOSでは無線LANは問題ありませんでした。

Ubuntuでwifiを見ると「wifiアダプターが装着されオンになっていることを確認してください」と出ますが、ネットワーク設定を見ると無線の項目がないので、networkmanagerのsystem-connectionsを見ると、フォルダーが空だったので、netplanの01-network-manager-all.yamlで具体的にSSIDとかを設定して、と考えたのですが設定の反映のnetplayコマンドがなくてインストール出来ませんでした。

`nmcli` コマンドで調べるとwlan0というチップはなくてenpls0しかなくてこれは利用不可になっていて、ドライバーの方は存在していることは分かっていますが、`iw dev` では何も表示が無かったので無線デバイスが消えたことになります。

Ubuntuで無線LANを有効にする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: おそらくドライバーやファームウェアがたりておらずにOSがwifiデバイスを認識できていないのでしょうが、搭載しているカード等はなんでしょうか。`lspci -v`や`lsusb`でみつけられるかもしれません。 [WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) [ワイヤレス設定 - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A) あたりが参考になるかと。

Comment: `netplay` は `netplan` の書き間違いでしょうか？